# How to detect right side of the page when pop-up menu is displayed and adjust position accordingly?

Tags: jquery, html, css, popup

I created a simple POP-UP menu where user can hide or display some submenu. Problem is that I'm not sure how to deal with situation where the menu is displayed all the way to the right, and when user clicks the menu, the pop-up displays out of the page to the right.

How to manage this?

```
$("#menu-item-1").click(function() 
    {
        var position = $(this).position();

        if ($("#menu-content-1").css("display") == "none")
        {
            $("#menu-content-1").css("display", "block");
            $("#menu-content-1").css("left", position.left);
            $("#menu-content-1").css("top", position.top + 50);
        }
        else
        {
            $("#menu-content-1").css("display", "none");
        }
    });
```

Here's jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zkg3n/

Comment: Instead of left position use the right position.

Comment: where you jfiddle example

Comment: can u Make a fiddle of your code pls !

Comment: Sure, here you go. http://jsfiddle.net/Zkg3n/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. The input box is to set the left margin for your link. type whatever number in there e.g. 590 will set left margin of your link to be 590px. Then click on the link so see the pop up automatically set its location. I also changed your code a little bit 
http://jsfiddle.net/Zkg3n/7/`fiddle`

Comment: small note, I noticed if page is big enough to being entirely displayed with some leisure and yet menu is bit enough, it still does some overflowing. never the less, thank you.

Comment: Ahh. Ic. Important note: you HAVE TO use variables a, b and c since straight outputs from jQuery might be tricky to predict and vary from time to time. Using variables a, b and c yields consistency.

Comment: I'm afraid the problem persist as code you have posted.

Comment: If possible, would you know the solution of this sub problem? I must get it solved and just asking the source :)

Comment: Uhh.. I'll have a look at the code tonight and reply asap. Sorry for the delay

Comment: Ok. Instead of looking for width of document, it's now changed to the width of window. I also changed the 20px extra white space into 2 px (make sure that you have a look at the comment). Here's the new link for the sub problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Zkg3n/15/

Answer (score 1):

test my code

```
.active{
   border:1px solid green;
    transition:position 1s linear;
    opacity:1;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/QURQy/

Comment: I see what you did there. But I'm afraid this is not quite what I'm looking for. This seems to stick to the left side of the page instead. I just added bunch of white space to the left of the link there. http://jsfiddle.net/QURQy/1/

Comment: no problem, up voted because you tried and because you used slidedown/up. i'll use that instead :)

Answer (score 0):

We could also measure the position of the object, then add width of the document, and finally subtract the width of the pop up. Therefore we will align the right side of the popup to the right side of the button.

```
$("#menu-item-4").click(function() 
{
    var elem = $("#menu-content-4");
    var parent = $("#menu-item-4");
    var p = $(this).position();

    if (elem.css("display") == "none")
    {
        parent.css("font-weight", "bold");

        elem.slideDown();
        elem.css("left", (p.left + parent.width()) - elem.width());
        elem.css("top", p.top + 50);
    }
    else
    {
        elem.slideUp();
    }
});
```